# Can a DynamoDB attribute store different type of data?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS DynamoDB to store some settings value, with only 2 attributes there, `settingName` and `settingValue`. The data type of `settingName` is a string. Different Items in that table can have different types `settingValue`, it can be a boolean, number, string, List or Map. Is it possible?

When we create the table, I know we have to defend the attribute, but not for all. If I didn't define the attribute `settingValue`, Then I can put any datatype into that attribute. Is this a proper way to do that?

I tried, and it worked, Just don't know if this is the right way.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s allowed. Only the partition and sort keys require fixed type definitions, the rest are flexible.

Just don’t expect to later build a GSI using the attribute of mixed type.